# How to stop appearing the default launch messages

Tags: appium

Whenever I am running my appium script it prints the below line every time before the @test annotation.

"io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C"

How to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Appium log level is set to DEBUG. You can change this with the `--log-level` CLI argument. As this message is at INFO level, you probably want to set to WARN or less.

The argument specifies the console and log file levels separately. For instance if you wanted your console output to be at WARN, but your log file to remain at DEBUG, you'd use `--log-level warn:debug`

More information can be found in [the official documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/server-args/).

Comment: No this helps to stop the message on the appium server console. I wanted to stop it on the eclipse console